# office 365 SharePoint app deployment

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

I have a paid for Office 365 Developer subscription and have been successfully creating and deploying "Autohosted" SharePoint Apps for the last couple of weeks.

However today when I fired up VS2012 and pressed "Deploy" nothing happened!  The deployment process runs but never ends.  I am never prompted to "Trust" the application.  It just hangs.

I have pasted the output from the deployment process below. The final output is "Installation is in progress (00:00:03)" .... and this keeps appearing every few seconds.  I left it for 35 minutes and it never completed.

I can see no error messages or think of any reason why this should have suddenly started happening.

I tried from a different developer machine to deploy to my Dev subscription and the same results occurred so I think it is related to my developer account.

Next I created a new developer "sub-site" and still get the same issue.

Any help, suggestions, or advice would be gratefully received!

===================================

Packaging into C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\obj\WebDeploy\TestApp.Web.zip.

1>  Package "TestApp.Web.zip" is successfully created as single file at the following location:

1>  file:///C:/Users/Tom/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/TestApp/TestApp/obj/WebDeploy

1>  To get the instructions on how to deploy the web package please visit the following link:

1>  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=124618

1>  Sample script for deploying this package is generated at the following location:

1>  C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\obj\WebDeploy\TestApp.Web.deploy.cmd

1>  For this sample script, you can change the deploy parameters by changing the following file:

1>  C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\obj\WebDeploy\TestApp.Web.SetParameters.xml

1>  Successfully created package at: C:\Users\Tom\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\bin\Release\app.publish\1.0.0.0\TestApp.app

2>------ Deploy started: Project: TestApp, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

2>Active Deployment Configuration: Deploy App for SharePoint

2>  Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.

2>  Skipping the uninstall step because the app for SharePoint is not installed on the server.

2>  Install app for SharePoint:

2>  Uploading the app for SharePoint...

2>  Installation is in progress (00:00:00)

2>  Installation is in progress (00:00:03)    **<----- Keeps repeating this line every 3 seconds for ever!**

Comment: i have the same problem. I think i only get this when i use a solution that once had a different SharePoint url.

Comment: What type of site collection are you deploying the app to?

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when i do quick debug sessions.  O365 is a Cloud form of SharePoint, so be in mind they have thousands of the same request.

With that in mind, make sure that you put at least 5 mins between your debug sessions.  That reduced the lag time between Uninstall and Reinstall.